# How to call a right bar button item on a UITabbarController class in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationitem

I Have programatically created a tabbar class which inherits from UITabBarController.

This is my code:

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    @class JourneyAppDelegate;

    @interface TTabBar :UITabBarController<UITabBarControllerDelegate> {
    UITabBarController *mTabController;
    JourneyAppDelegate *app;
    }


    #import "TTabBar.h"
    #import "TAddNewJourney.h"
    #import "TJourneylistController.h"
    #import "TAppStoreController.h"
    #import "TSettingsController.h"
    #import "TAboutController.h"
    #import "TReviewsController.h"
    #import "JourneyAppDelegate.h"

    @implementation TTabBar

    // The designated initializer.  Override if you create the controller programmatically and want to perform customization that is not appropriate for viewDidLoad.
    /*
    - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
        self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
        if (self) {
            // Custom initialization.
        }
        return self;
    }
    */

    /*
    // Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
    - (void)loadView {
    }
    */

    -(void)Add
    {

        app= (JourneyAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
        TAddNewJourney *j=[[TAddNewJourney alloc]init];
        [app.navigationController pushViewController:j animated:YES];
        [j release];



    }



    // Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    - (void)viewDidLoad {

        [super viewDidLoad];
        self.navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:nil];

        TJourneylistController *journeylist =[[TJourneylistController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        //UINavigationController *journeylistnavigation =[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:journeylist];

        //this is to provide the right navigation button item
        UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                       initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd
                                       target:self
                                       action:@selector(Add)] autorelease];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;

        [journeylist.tabBarItem initWithTitle:@"Journey List" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"newJourney.png"] tag:1];
        journeylist.navigationItem.title =@"Journey List";
        //[journeylist release];

        TAppStoreController *appstore =[[TAppStoreController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        //UINavigationController *appstorenavigation =[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:appstore];
        [appstore.tabBarItem initWithTitle:@"App Store" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"appStore.png"] tag:2];

        appstore.navigationItem.title = @"App Store";
        //[appstore release];

        TSettingsController *settings =[[TSettingsController  alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        //UINavigationController *settingsnavigation =[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:settings];
        [settings.tabBarItem initWithTitle:@"Settings" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings.png"] tag:3];
        settings.navigationItem.title = @"Settings";
        //[settings release];

        TAboutController *about =[[TAboutController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        //UINavigationController *aboutnavigation =[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:about];
        [about.tabBarItem initWithTitle:@"About" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"contactUs.png"] tag:4];
        about.navigationItem.title =@"About Us";


    //  [about release];

        NSArray *controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:journeylist,appstore,settings,about,nil];
        //self.viewControllers = controllers;
        self.viewControllers = controllers;
        //[controllers release];
    }



i need a right navigation item on the class Journeylistcontroller.So i have added it to the code but the problem is the navigtaion item gets set to the four controllers.i need that only journeylistcontroller should have the navigation item.Please can anybody help me in solving this problem.Thanks
```

Comment: what do you mean by "calling a right button bar item"? sorry, it is not clear to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need to display barbutton item in only one view, then create a navigationController and Journeylistcontroller to that view controller and then, add created navigationcontroller to the array.
Also, u need to add rightbarbutton item to the created navigation controller not to self.navigationController.
**Edit:**

```
TJourneylistController *journeylist =[[TJourneylistController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

[journeylist.tabBarItem initWithTitle:@"Journey List" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"newJourney.png"] tag:1];

        journeylist.navigationItem.title =@"Journey List";
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:journeylist];
                    navController.navigationBar.hidden=YES;


UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                       initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd
                                       target:self
                                       action:@selector(Add)] autorelease];
        navController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
```

try this , also add navController to array not journeylist

Comment: Hi sripriya, i am not clear what you are saying. if possible could you please provide me sample code

Comment: i think what she ment to say is that if you wana show the UIBarButton Item in only one view then create the bar button item and assign it to the navigation controller with the help of the following code:

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = YourBarButtonObject;

I think this is what she meants

Now if you meant by calling the function that was assigned to the barbutton item on your tabbar then in that case i would say use the below code

[self callingBarButton_Function];

Comment: @Rocky: I added the code in my answer, try it and please let me know.